# T-SQL how to retrieve true or false or both in where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have following table in `sql server`

```
ItemID OrderID  personId  Active
1       1         1         0
2       1         1         1
3       1         1         1
4       1         1         1
```

i have stored procedure

```
GetRecords(@OrderId,@PersonId, @Active)

select * from Records where OrderID = @orderId and PersonId = @PersonId
```

that brings records based on OrderID, PersonID 
now I want to apply additional filter based on `@Active` 
if its active then bring only active records 
if its not active bring both active and inactive
how do I achieve this in where clause

Comment: `AND (@Active = 0 OR (@Active = 1 AND Active = 1))`. Another one could be `AND CASE WHEN @Active = 0 THEN 1 WHEN @Active = 1 AND Active = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * 
from Records 
where OrderID = @orderId and PersonId = @PersonId and 
      ((@active = 1 and active = 1) or (@active = 0))
```

Comment: @sagi it might be more understandable, but they are completely different

Comment: @Lamak Huh, guess I'm tired. Lets forget about this:)